# Docker failed to login from CLI

Tags: docker

I just installed a fresh docker in mac . And eventhough i can login to docker hub using gui , i can't login to docker hub using terminal.

According to error message, its related with certificate, but i didn't need to do any thing with certificate previously.

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for *.kneura.com, not registry-1-docker.io
```

Comment: Do you have a school firewall / content blocker? I suspect your connection to `registry-1.docker.io` is being intercepted and replaced with a block page served by `kneura.com` which is a classroom management software company.

Comment: no any firewall

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error, which I was able to fix today. So I'm not sure which operating system you're on or whether that I would make a difference. I'm using Pop-os, which is based on Ubuntu.

I had a file on my computer in /etc called hosts, so the full path is /etc/hosts. The file had this in it:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
127.0.1.1 pop-os.localdomain pop-os
34.228.211.243 registry-1.docker.io
```

So it turns out that the docker registry is hosted on AWS with an elastic IP address, so it changes over time. The 34.228.211.243 address is currently taken by the Kunera.com company. To fix this issue, all you have to do is curl for the current IP address from the registry like so:

```
curl -v https://index.docker.io:443
```

Then, replace the old ip address in /etc/hosts with the new valid IP. Try running

```
docker run hello-world
```

and everything should work now. Credit to this post for helping me solve it. [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399671/add-dockerhub-ip-addresses-on-whitelist).

According to that post, it's a bad idea to whitelist the docker registry IP, so I'm curious if it would be better practice to remove that entire line from the /etc/hosts file?